# chat website in jsp/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, livechat

I want to devlelop a chat website using JSP/Servlets and Tomcat. I have following questions:

1. Can the website handle load (1000 people at one time) without slowing down?
2. Will it cause the website to slow down? What is the ideal server configuration for this kind of website? Note that I don't have a huge budget to host.
3. How can I implement server push?
4. Will PHP or JSP be ideal for such website?

Comment: I don't think making such a thing is worth it, unless you are experimenting and learning.

Comment: because it is hard to implement properly, and you seem to be inexperienced (no offence with that)

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends entirely on hardware/software. It will obviously run faster on a Quadcore Xeon server from 2010 than an Octa Pentium Pro server from 2000. It will also obviously run and scale better if the code is written efficiently and the server is configured to an optimum.
2. See 1. I'd suggest to use [the NIO connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html) in Tomcat.
3. You can use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) for this. In Tomcat, it's available by [AIO (Advanced IO)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html).
4. Depends entirely on your own skillset. But technically, JSP/Servlet will likely scale better with this.

Answer (score 0):

why re-invent the wheel? Just use an XMPP client. Here are some good [clients](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml) and [claros](http://www.claros.org/web/showProduct.do?id=2) in particular is a good one.