# How to create an Live chat in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

How to create a Live CHat application in JSP. Basically i am creating a management system whicch i want it to allow user to live chatting with admin. Any clue or suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [chat website in jsp/servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477135/chat-website-in-jsp-servlet) and more (see "Related")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libraries like J-Live Chat (http://www.j-livesupport.com/)  or JChatBox (http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/jchatbox/jchatbox.html) that can be included into your Web Modules